# Show facebook status stream of a dedicated person on a website

Tags: php, api, facebook

I've been stomping at this all day :(

I want to display a status feed of both twitter and facebook on my website. For twitter, this is not a problem, as my account is public, I can easily get the feed.
Facebook however, is a whole different story! I can't seem to find an easy way to just get my last status updates and display it on my website.
The code I currently have, needs authentication of the visitor, and I don't want that!

This is my current code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook($api_key, $secret);
$stream = $facebook->api_client->fql_query("SELECT message,source,time FROM status WHERE uid = $user_id LIMIT 6");
```

I've seen several possible solutions, including the RSS feed, but as Facebook keeps changing the way their site works, none of the previous methods I've seen (including those from as late as januari) currently work!

Is there anybody who can provide me with a currently working solution to this (simple?) problem?

Comment: Try developer pages at facebook.
Also consider buying Facebook Cookbook from O'Reilly: http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596518172/

Comment: Are you positive that it's in there before I throw away $30?

Comment: You can browse the contents before you buy. See this facility on the page. There might be a similar solution that you could extend to meet your requirements. You might also want to consider using Drupal as your website content management system - as this provides functionality for connecting to facebook. Drupal is free and open source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this using the offline access feature in facebook. Take a look at [the symfony plugin I created for this](https://github.com/pascaldevink/sfSocialMediaPlugin).

Comment: Did'nt found the page. Do you still have the solution? Thanks!

Comment: @Sisir : The updated link is : https://github.com/pascaldevink/sfSocialMediaPlugin . I posted an edit of the answer that should be accepted soon.

Answer (score 0):

"The code I currently have, needs authentication of the visitor..."

Can you host a proxy page or service that accepts anonymous requests from your visitors then makes an authenticated request on their behalf?

Comment: I could, by would facebook allow me to do such a thing?

Comment: If its your status that you are displaying and its your credentials that you are using to authenticate then i would be shocked if you would be violating terms of service. Also, as far as FB knows, you are making a request from one source IP (IP of your proxy) so there should be no reason to be alarmed from their perspective. Check their developer guides/docs but im sure this would work without violating any TOS

Answer (score 0):

You deffinitely need to utilize the authorization before accessing any information of any of friends you may have. That is how Facebook works, it is not as open as Buzz or Twitter.